EVENTO CON MYSQL
tengo una consulta. Deseo que los datos que tengo en una tabla se repitan en la misma tabla cada inicio de mes (excepto el id), ya que mensualmente debo generar esos registros pero debo dejar los anteriores como históricos con sus fechas. Se puede hacer un CREATE EVENT para eso y asi lograr que sea automáticamente sin intervención humana? Gracias
